# Overcoming autocomplete=Off in Safari 11

Tags: safari, auto-complete

Does there anybody knows a script, that will make Safari ignore the autocomplete=off statement that prevents Safari from using Autofill on a web page input field? Like the old extension "Autocomplete Always On" for Safari 4 and 5. I find only a statement to this old extension (http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2010/06/10/safari-extension-autocomplete/). 
I know the reasons for Safari's honoring that command, but for myself, I'd like to override it.

Greetings Andy

Comment: why don't you just turn autofill on in the preferences.

Comment: ...because autofill won't work if the site tells it not to - try your bank, for instance.

Comment: If its passwords just delete them from Safari.

Comment: @MelvinJefferson - I'm pretty sure the OP is to do the opposite - **make** Safari autofill where it currently refuses to - like bank accounts etc. I currently have to use a 3rd party app for that type of site, so I'm interested in answers to this too.

Comment: That feature is not available for safari yet

Comment: It used to be overridable; then they broke it & made everybody go back to simple & shared passwords rather than be able to autocomplete something complex & non-memorable. imnsho, a poor decision.